# Geolocation with timeout causes error handler to be called twice

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

Let's take this faily simple example:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    function() { /* yay! */},
    function(error) { console.log(error) },
    {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 5000
    }
);
```

Open up the dev tools in chrome. Click on the emulation tab > sensors > "Emulate position unavailable". Then paste this code into the console.

Immediately you will receive the following log:

```
PositionError {message: "PositionUnavailable", code: 2, PERMISSION_DENIED: 1, POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: 2, TIMEOUT: 3}
```

Then 5 seconds later you will receive:

```
PositionError {message: "Timeout expired", code: 3, PERMISSION_DENIED: 1, POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: 2, TIMEOUT: 3}
```

Is this really how the API is designed or is this a bug in the `navigator.geolocation` implementation in chrome?

The callback that is being called twice is messing with some of my display code. Is there any way to bundle the errors together for that request or just ignore the timeout if we already received a `PositionUnavailable`?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I still think the behavior is weird but I've found a way to reliably bundle the errors together.

Here is some psuedo-code for this example:

```
(function() {

    var detectionId = 0;

    var detectionErrors = {};

    var success = function() {};

    var error = function(id, error) {
        if (detectionErrors[id]) {
            return;
        }

        detectionErrors[id] = error;

        console.log(error);
    };

    document.getElementById('whatever').addEventListener('click', function() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            success,
            error.bind(null, detectionId),
            {
                enableHighAccuracy: true,
                timeout: 5000
            }
        );

        detectionId++;
    });


})();
```